# Cannot get Azure cmdlet Get-AzureRMAuthorizationChangeLog to work

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to use the Azure PowerShell cmdlet "Get-AzureRMAuthorizationChangeLog". I keep getting the error that the term is not recognized.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-access-change-history-report
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Storage/1.0.6/Content/ResourceManagerStartup.ps1

I have AzureRM and AzureRM.Storage installed, both at the latest versions.

What am I missing?

Comment: this is interesting. I've tried various versions of this module, this cmdlet is not available in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

To work around that you can do this:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM.Storage\2.3.0"
. .\ResourceManagerStartup.ps1
```